# Declare a variable type depending on a ternary expression

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, variable-declaration

I have to export data from a database in `XML` or `CSV` depending of the user choice.
I stock the choice like this:

```
const bool isXml = (cbxFormat->currentIndex() == 1 ? true : false);
```

And to write the export file, I use a `QXmlStreamWriter` or a `QTextStream`.
I want to avoid `if/else` statement to declare my stream.
I have try to use `decltype` like this:

```
decltype( (isXml ? QXmlStreamWriter() : QTextStream()) ) stream;
```

But I can't because `QXmlStreamWriter` and `QTextStream` haven't same base class and in the case of the base class is the same, the type of `stream` is the "widest" type.

I also tried to use `std::conditional` but I can't because isXml is known at runtime:

```
std::conditional<isXml, QXmlStreamWriter, QTextStream>::type stream;
```

Is it exist a possible solution to do that ?

```
QFile expFile(fileName);
if (expFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    /* not possible */
    // decltype( (isXml ? QXmlStreamWriter() : QTextStream()) ) stream;
    /* isXml is known at runtime */
    // std::conditional<isXml, QXmlStreamWriter, QTextStream>::type stream(&expFile);
    // If not possible... if/else

    // filling my stream..

    expFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a function that has the type as template argument and invoke the function with the appropriate type using an `if`:

```
template <typename StreamT>
void do_work(QFile& file) {
    StreamT stream;
    // ...
    stream << strData;
}

void work() {
  QFile file(file_name);
  // ...
  if (isXml) {
    do_work<QXmlStreamWriter>(file);
  } else {
    do_work<QTextStream>(file);
  }
}
```

---

EDIT:

Another solution would be to wrap your stream in classes:

```
struct stream_base {
  virtual void work(QFile&) = 0;
};
struct xml_stream: stream_base {
  virtual void work(QFile&) { QXmlStreamWriter stream; ... }
};
struct text_stream: stream_base {
  virtual void work(QFile&) { QTextStream stream; ... }
};
std::unique_ptr<stream_base> make_stream(bool isXml) {
  return isXml ? std::make_unique<xml_stream>() : std::make_unique<text_stream> ();
}

void work () {
  QFile file (file_name);
  // ...
  auto stream = make_stream(isXml);
  stream->work(file);
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a possibility, but there is really no way to have a declaration depending on value of another variable ?

Comment: @ThibautB. You cannot choose the type based on a variable that is known at runtime-time, because the type is deduced at compile-time. You could write a class that wraps your streams though; I've edited my answer to add an example.

Comment: you can combine the two: have a `template<typename StreamT> struct stream_impl : stream_base ...`

Comment: @piwi. Thank you for this confirmation